# How show diff. HTML based on property in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a collection of objects that are of types: `text`, `selectoptions` and `multiselectoptions`. I need to display them as editable inputs based on their type.

For example, a text object:

```
<input type="text" name="caption" value="{{option.value}}" />
```

A selectoption/multiselectoptions:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in option.values">
    <input type="text" name="{{option.id}}[value][{{value.id}}]" value="{{value.value}}" />
    <input type="text" name="{{option.id}}[caption][{{value.id}}]" value="{{value.caption}}" />
</div>
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a better way to represent it?

Example of the JSON objects:

```
FORM: {
    options: [
        {
            type: "select",
            values: [
                {
                    value: 0,
                    caption: "Some option"
                },
                {
                    value: 1,
                    caption: "Some other option"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            caption: "Some text item"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ng-if to display the correct form element based on your model. Here is an example in [plunker based on your code.](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hh1m2n7CsiqGtBIHyJkz?p=preview)

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <div ng-repeat="field in FORM.options">
        <input type="text" ng-model='field.caption' ng-if="field.type == 'text'" /><br />
        <div ng-if="field.type != 'text'">
             <div ng-repeat="value in field.values">
                Option: <input type="text" name="{{option.id}}[value][{{value.id}}]" value="{{value.value}}" /><br/>
                Caption: <input type="text" name="{{option.id}}[caption][{{value.id}}]" value="{{value.caption}}" /><br/>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
</form>
```

I  check the type `field.type` and display different HTML in the main ng-repeat.

The app assign your model to FORM:

```
$scope.FORM =  {
    options: [
        {
            type: "select",
            values: [
                {
                    value: 0,
                    caption: "Some option"
                },
                {
                    value: 1,
                    caption: "Some other option"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            type: "text",
            caption: "Some text item"
        }
    ]
};
```

I also added a submit button that display the model in the Javascript console, so you can see that the data is being updated when you change the values:

```
<button ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
```

Comment: I used a combination of this and `ng-include="text.html"` so i could put the different layouts in their own files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-switch` which will switch to corresponding HTML based on the `type` from the JSON.

```
<div ng-repeat="opt in FORM.options" ng-switch on="opt.type">
    <select ng-switch-when="select">
        <option ng-repeat="val in opt.values" value='{{val.value}}'>{{val.caption}}</option>
     </select>

   <input type="text" ng-model="opt.caption"  ng-switch-when="text"/>
</div>
```

Add more MultiSelect types with `ng-switch-when = "multiselect"`. If the `type` is not specified, set a `ng-switch-default` to default html.

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VpILdQWX1ZUiV60ZOVI6?p=preview)